# Find folder with most entries - unix (bash)

Tags: bash, unix

I've been working to try to figure out how I might search all directories under the current one and see which directory has the most files but I am having no such luck thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do it:

```
find * -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1| cut -d/ -f1| sort| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -1;
```

If you want to include directories that begin with a `.` you can modify it thusly:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2| cut -d/ -f2| sort| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -1;
```

The above commands will leave in the entry count to the left of the winning directory name; you can remove the count (and thus just get the directory name, which could be useful for scripting) by piping through the following filter:

```
...| sed -E 's/^\s*[0-9]+\s*//;';
```

Comment: Very nice. Though I'd probably replace the entire `cut ....` pipeline with `awk -F / '{map[$2]++} END {max=-1; for (dir in map) {if (max < map[dir]) {max=map[dir]; ret=dir}} print ret}'` personally.